# How to change encryption algorithm for MapReduce Shuffle

Tags: java, hadoop, encryption

From our test, it looks like Hadoop Shuffle uses DES encryption by default: ECDHE-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:112,EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:112,DES-CBC3-SHA:112.

How to set it to use AES?

Are these the correct ones to set?
hadoop.security.crypto.cipher.suite=AES/CTR/NoPadding
dfs.encrypt.data.transfer.cipher.suites=AES/CTR/NoPadding

Comment: My question is which Hadoop settings should be used to set MapReduce ShuffleHandler to use AES.

Comment: I found 2 but not sure if they are the correct places to set: hadoop.security.crypto.cipher.suite=AES/CTR/NoPadding , dfs.encrypt.data.transfer.cipher.suites=AES/CTR/NoPadding

Answer (score 0):

For AES you could use `ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256` or `ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384`.

See [Supported SSL / TLS ciphersuites](https://tls.mbed.org/supported-ssl-ciphersuites) section *RSA with Elliptic Curve Ephemeral Diffie Hellman (ECDHE-RSA) key exchange*.

Comment: My question is which hadoop configuration I should use to set AES for ShuffleHandler.

Comment: Note that the DES version uses `CBC` mode not `CTR` mode.

Answer (score 0):

For shuffling hadoop uses it's internal algorithm from **org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.task.reduce.Shuffle** file the default algorithm can be changed by using **org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ShuffleConsumerPlugin** property