# Which Hadoop settings are for encryption algorithm of MapReduce ShuffleHandler?

Tags: hadoop, encryption, mapreduce, aes, shuffle

I want to set ShuffleHandler to use AES instead of DES. I found 2 parameters but not sure if they are the ones to set:

1) HDFS encryption:
hadoop.security.crypto.cipher.suite=AES/CTR/NoPadding,
2) Block data transfer encryption: dfs.encrypt.data.transfer.cipher.suites=AES/CTR/NoPadding

Comment: Similar to [yesterdays question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/37580694/451475).

Comment: CTR is a streaming mode not a block mode, CBC is a block mode. Streaming modes do not need padding, block modes do.

Comment: Hi Zaph, are you saying for Block Data Encryption, the setting should be dfs.encrypt.data.transfer.cipher.suites=AES/CBC/Padding?

Comment: I can't tell because the DES code/usage is not provided. CBC mode will require an iv, are you using an iv with the DES code?